# React.js: Convert this kind of array format to JSON

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass an argument to an axios post request

Normally what I need is this kind of JSON

```
[{"moduleId":"ASDJI-1212JSDF-12412SN"}]
```

This would come from clicking a value in a listbox and moving it to the right

I have this code where I push the value of the listbox to an array state

```
    const [selectedModules, setSelectedModules] = useState([]);

    const retrieveActionsList = useCallback(() => {
        ProfileMaintenanceService.retrieveActionsList(selectedModules)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log("ProfileMaintenancePage - retrieveActionsList response.data >>> " + response.data)
          console.log("ProfileMaintenancePage - retrieveActionsList JSON.stringify(response.data) >>> " + JSON.stringify(response.data))
          setListboxActions(response.data);
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log("ProfileMaintenancePage - retrieveActionsList catch >>> " + err)
        })
      });

     const handleOnChange = (selected) => {
        console.log("selected " + selected)
        selectedModules.push(selected);
        retrieveActionsList()
      };

    return (
    <DualListBox
                    options={ newOptionsListbox }
                    selected={ selectedModules }
                    onChange={ handleOnChange }
                    showHeaderLabels={ true }
                    disabled={ disabled }

                />

    )
```

Somehow, I'm getting this value:

`[["C77C1031-2714-483D-AE59-21C9CD5EBAEF"]]`

Would like to ask for help how to convert this to proper JSON format.

TIA

EDIT:

axios request

```
/* API for populating actions in listbox */
    retrieveActionsList(selectedModules) {
        return axios.post(`${API_URL_RETRIEVE_ACTIONS}`,
        [
            {
                moduleId: selectedModules
            }
        ]
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to push a new object to `selectedModules` and for doing that u need to use `setSelectedModules()` like this.

Instead of

```
selectedModules.push(selected);
```

Use this,

```
setSelectedModules([...selectedModules,{moduleId:selected}]);
```

Modifying the state variable `selectedModules` directly does not cause a re-render and may not reflect the required change in the UI.

**Update**

Given the format the response has, you also need to do a map operation on the response before setting it to state.

```
setSelectedModules(
    response.data[0].map((id)=>({moduleId: id} )
);
```

Comment: If modifying state variable may not reflect the required change, how should I access the value of the state?

Comment: How does the response look like when there are two module ids? 
Like this ? [["asdf-sdfs-sdf"],["asfa-asdfa"]]

Comment: You can access the value directly. But to update you need to use the setter.

Comment: It looks like this `[["4E948025-1F1B-41E2-A18D-55AD8646810B","C77C1031-2714-483D-AE59-21C9CD5EBAEF"]]`

Comment: You also need to do a map().. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: The map is not working. Note that there's not yet a response from the API here, I'm only building the request from onchange of the listbox, wherein the JSON format should be like this `[{"moduleId":"id"}]`

Comment: I trigger the onChange when a listbox item is moved to the right. With this, I'm also pushing to the state array as seen on the `handleOnChange` method

Comment: Added the axios request. Please see my edit. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211045/discussion-between-user54321-and-iamjpcbau).